# Open XML plugin and parse using element tree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, plugins, qgis

I make plugin in QGIS to open and read XML file, then parse it and show scale map from it, its a big xml file and line with scale information have format like this

```
<gmd:denominator>
<gco:Integer>ScaleValue</gco:Integer>
</gmd:denominator>
```

and i try code like this to open xml file and then parse it:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from ui_latih import Ui_latih
# create the dialog for zoom to point


class latihDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_latih()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        cariButton = self.ui.btnCari
        QtCore.QObject.connect(cariButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.cari)

    def cari(self, event=None):

        #open dialog
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '*.xml')

        self.ui.lineFile.setText(filename)

        #call text
        self.isiDataFile(filename)

    def isiDataFile(self, nmfile):
        #open with read mode
        teksFile = open(nmfile, 'r').read()

        self.ui.textFile.setText(teksFile)

    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    doc = tree.getroot()

    for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/gmd:denominator'):
        x = elem.tag, elem.text
        self.ui.lineSkala.setText(x)

    for elem in doc.findall('Default_Config/gmd:MD_Format'):
        y = elem.tag, elem.text
        self.ui.lineFitur.setText(y)
```

I try using Element Tree to parse and show ScaleValue in LineEdit because its integrated in python, but i have error message like this :

```
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

i am really newbie in python and xml parser, can i pass the xml location from open xml code to

```
tree = ET.parse( )
```

because i plan to open more than one xml file and scale in one and another xml file have different value as well

Can Someone help me?

Comment: I edited my post because i get a new error message and can someone tell me how to pass xml location from open xml code above to

tree = ET.parse( )

because i plan to parse more than one xml file